# highlight link with condition file does not exist

Tags: vimscript, syntax-highlighting

For a wiki syntax plugin, i'd like to have two highlighting colors for links. Links already having a destination file should be green and links with no destination yet should be red.

```
[[This file exist]] (green)
  filereadable("/wiki/dir/this_file_exist.md") -> true

[[File does not exist]] (red) 
  (filereadable("/wiki/dir/file_does_not_exist.md")-> false
```

Is it possible in vim to run file validation code based on a region match?

Comment: Maybe you can write an autocmd to use global to search your link, if it's readable, call matchaddpos to highlight it, but that command works window, i don't know how to restrict it to buffer only.

Comment: @dedowsdi you helped me get started, I ended up using matchadd inside a function called by autocmd.

Comment: Glad you made it.